# out of memory error for files greater than 3Mb though upload using chunk

Tags: java, android

```
double bytes = file.length();
                                    double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);  
                                    double megaBytes = (kilobytes/1024);


                                if(megaBytes<10)
                                {
                                    filesize = Double.toString(kilobytes);
                                    System.out.println("kilobytes String : " + filesize);
                                    try
                                    {
                                        arrByteFile = null;

                                        int bytesRead;
                                        int bufferSize = 1024;
                                        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
                                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                        byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];

                                        while ((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) 
                                        {
                                            bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
                                        }

                                        arrByteFile = bos.toByteArray();
                                        is.close();

                                        System.out.println("File byte array Size:-"+arrByteFile.length);
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                    try 
                                    {
                                        ChunkOfByteArray chunkOfByteArray = new ChunkOfByteArray(arrByteFile);
                                        arrayList = chunkOfByteArray.getChunksOfByteArray();
                                    } 
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

how to handle out of memory error??

is there anyway to upload large file in Base64 format ..??

i am using AQuery jar for API calls  and using chunks to upload file. but it gives error while creating chunks only.

Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not sending the data as you read it.  You are creating a large buffer which doesn't help you at all because a file can be read in one go if you needed this, but you don't.

Just send the data as you read it and you won't use more memory for larger files. I.e. instead of writing to `bos` write straight to the socket output stream.

BTW You can use Base64, but this is larger and would use more memory (unless you sent the data as you read it as I suggested)

Comment: Yes sir.. for large files may be i will have to do that. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @nadafafif this way you will use 1 KB (for your byte[]) regardless of the file size.

Answer (score -1):

Go to AndroidManifest.xml file and put this :

> android:largeHeap="true"

For example:

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="pt.example.test"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  </application>
```