# Bitmap resizing causes out of memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have a simple class for resizing bitmap images according to my requirement. There is a simple method responsible for it as follows:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeRichImages(Bitmap bitmap, Context mContext){
        try {
        float originalBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        float originalBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        float originalAspectRatio = originalBitmapWidth/originalBitmapHeight;
        double width_percentage = (0.05*screenWidthPixels(mContext));
        float newWidth = (float)((int)screenWidthPixels(mContext)-width_percentage);
        float newBitmapWidth = newWidth;
        float newBitmapHeight = newBitmapWidth/originalAspectRatio;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) newWidth, (int)newBitmapHeight, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;

    }
```

And this is how I call this method:

```
String URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.86527274921529,151.2050531328867&zoom=15&size=640x360&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C-33.86527274921529,151.2050531328867";

try {
bmp = Picasso.with(ViewStory.this).load(URL)
                                                            .get();
bmp = ImageController.ResizeRichImages(bmp, ViewStory.this);
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
```

But, almost every time I am getting the out of memory exception while calling the ResizeRichImages method. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what is screenWidthPixels(mContext)

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296344/out-of-memory-error-for-files-greater-than-3mb-though-upload-using-chunk/26296433#26296433

Comment: `"android:largeHeap"` only hides the problem ... normaly **you shouldn't use it** ... but it is commonly used by bad programmers(without knowledge and skills) and noobs

Comment: ... also ... Picasso has it's own resize method ... why didn't you use it

Comment: @Selvin did not get to do it with Picasso, have you any sample code?

Comment: @pbespechnyi **[Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being allocated and why it must be retained](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#CheckHowMuchMemory)**

Comment: first check if you are not UPSCALING also you have `size=640x360` in url ... maybe you could use it ... and finally you can use `.resize(MAX_SIZE_LENGTH, MAX_SIZE_LENGTH).centerInside()`

Comment: @Selvin, yeah, you're right almost for all cases, but you also shouldn't ignore the case when you want to see something working and when iteratively refactor the code. Based on the code I see, it's the case.

Comment: *and when iteratively refactor the code* ... hahahahahahaha ... `android:largeHeap` will stay in the manifest forever .... almost for all cases ...

Comment: @Selvin the .resize(MAX_SIZE_LENGTH, MAX_SIZE_LENGTH).centerInside() is not working and weirdly it is not at all showing the image anymore!

Answer (score 0):

- Instead using largeHeap option in manifest which should be always last option, you can try compressing like below code snippet.

*

byteArrImage = null;

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
if(data != null) thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
if(thumbnail != null) {
    //thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, baos);
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, baos);
    byteArrImage = baos.toByteArray();
    uploadImageToServer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error before, but After some searching i found another way to resize large Bitmap image. When you use Bitmap with large image you have to scale image with BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize . The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. When you use inSampleSize = 4 it returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original.You can also see the more detail in android developer site.

Use this Method for resizing

```
private Bitmap decodeFileWithSmallSize(String sdcard_path) {
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdcard_path, options);
return myBitmap;
}
```

Use in Activity

```
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
    }
    bitmap = decodeFileWithSmallSize("path");
} 
catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
{
    Log.e("TAG",
            "OutOfMemoryError Exception" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You know that he already has a Bitmap from Picasso? how this answer apply to his question? Or it is you universal answer for all OOME's questions?

Answer (score 0):

Generally while deal with bitmap we need to reduce the memory size by reducing the samplesize of bitmap based on our required width and height.

This functions takes bitmap file path if you want to pass bitmap change it with your requirement.But this the proper way to load images efficently.

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

This function  calculates the sample size of required image in order to reduct he memory..

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

For more info refer this link:http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

In your case if you are targeting min level as 19 then go with **reconfigure function** which is available on api level 19
[visit developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#reconfigure(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config))

Comment: You know that he already has a Bitmap from Picasso? how this answer apply to his question? Or it is you universal answer for all OOME's questions?

Comment: @Selvin can u please see the question clearly already he got an bitmap(on code named as bmp)  and while trying to resize it he got error.

Comment: @Selvin he doesn't have any problem until he call ResizeRichImages function

Comment: Do you even understand your code ... **he had decoded bitmap** ... your code will (eventually)works with not decoded yet ... it checks size of original image without decoding and then decode the smaller bitmap ...

Answer (score -1):

You haven't told us how big your bitmap is. Perhaps it's simply using up all of your free memory, especially if you have other large bitmaps (or something else) taking up much of it.

I would try running the procedure on a small bitmap, and with newBitmapWidth and newBitmapHeight reduced to a tenth of what they are now. If this eliminates the exception, it's pretty sure you need to optimize your memory use before you can handle the full size.

Comment: The image can be as big as what you download from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.86527274921529,151.2050531328867&zoom=15&size=640x360&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C-33.86527274921529,151.2050531328867